# Setup of Amazon Cloudfront with EC2 instance as origin and custom domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Can you guys help me out in identifying  what I am doing wrong in setting up the cloudfront for my ec2 instance (web server) for a custom domain of mine.

I am using my domain name (www.example.com) as the origin domain name.

I have also supplied a certificate to the cloudfront (*.example.com) using ACM.

The problem I am facing is, when i point out my custom domain name to the cloud fronts domain name in route53 using an alias record.

My website responds with an error 502. I'll really appreciate any help. I have explored all the content provided by AWS in respect to this but nothing seems to work till now.

Comment: Does it work if you point to Route 53 directly (using the cloudfront.net domain name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most 502 from CloudFront caused by the SSL communication between CloudFront and Origin.
CloudFront makes sure that your origin:
1.Has Trusted certificate
2. Ciphers matches 
3. CloudFront uses the SNI filed in Client hello which is defined as Origin domain name, it most cases if you have cert on EC2 with www.example.com CN, you can forward HOST header and it should solve your problem.

- If you don't have HTTPS running on Origin, you can select HTTP only in Origin protocol policy as its bydefault set to Viewer match.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html

Comment: I believe I will try forwarding the HOST header otherwise the only option left is to us HTTP only.